# Content between rows in html table

Tags: html, html-table

I need to have a table where each row can have a child table or other content below that row.

Is there any valid way to do this?

Comment: So you just mean a table within a table? Its 100% doable without questions, its like adding a `<div>` inside a `<div>`

Comment: @Jakub ...wait, you can put a `div` in a `div`? So you can `div` while you `div` your `div` ?

Comment: @alex... you `div`, we `div`, they all `div`...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add another `<tr>` *after* the current one with a `colspan` which spans all columns and then put another `<td>` with a `<table>` therein.

```
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan="3">
        <table>...</table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>col1</td>
    <td>col2</td>
    <td>col3</td>
</tr>
```

The new table will then appear between the rows.

Comment: `colspan` should be on `<td>`, not `<tr>`

Answer (score 5):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                 problem?
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It can at least form a layout problem if he has multiple columns and would like to have the new table span all columns. That's at least the common layout requirement.

Comment: @BalusC Sure, I assume the OP is handy with `colspan` attribute :)

Comment: This question at its whole own gives me the impression he wasn't *that* handy :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't put anything inside a table between the rows, all content has to be inside the table cells.

You can add another row, and use `colspan` to make it contain a single cell that spans the width of the table, and put the content in that cell.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no valid way. Only td-s and th-s are allowed in tr
You can however put only 1 td in the row, and set it's colspan attribute to the number of columns you have in the table.